# HTML, resized embed pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have embedded a pdf using this javascript function:

```
screenshotPreview = function(filename){    

    $("#body").append("<p><embed src=" + filename + " type='application/pdf' width='60%' height='60%' class='pdf_image'></p>");                           

};
```

However, the width and height adjustment doesn't resize the pdf, it just trims the pdf window size, so the user still needs to scroll within this window to see the whole pdf.

Any suggestions? I've tried using 
      scale='tofit' 
as well, but see no change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale the container not the embed.

Answer (score 1):

Scale the containing div, not the embed.